# Why is count function is not working with mapvalues in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing some basic handson in spark using scala.

I would like to know why the count function is not working with **mapValues** and **map** function

When I apply **sum,min,max** then it works..  Also Is there any place where I can refer all the applicable functions that can be applied on  Iterable[String] from groupbykeyRDD?

**MyCode:**

```
scala> val records = List( "CHN|2", "CHN|3" , "BNG|2","BNG|65")
records: List[String] = List(CHN|2, CHN|3, BNG|2, BNG|65)

scala> val recordsRDD = sc.parallelize(records)
recordsRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[119] at parallelize at <console>:23

scala> val mapRDD = recordsRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\|"))
mapRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[120] at map at <console>:25

scala> val keyvalueRDD = mapRDD.map(elem => (elem(0),elem(1)))
keyvalueRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[121] at map at <console>:27

scala> val groupbykeyRDD = keyvalueRDD.groupByKey()
groupbykeyRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = ShuffledRDD[122] at groupByKey at <console>:29

scala> groupbykeyRDD.mapValues(elem => elem.count).collect
<console>:32: error: missing arguments for method count in trait  TraversableOnce;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          groupbykeyRDD.mapValues(elem => elem.count).collect
                                               ^

scala> groupbykeyRDD.map(elem => (elem._1 ,elem._2.count)).collect
<console>:32: error: missing arguments for method count in trait TraversableOnce;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          groupbykeyRDD.map(elem => (elem._1 ,elem._2.count)).collect
```

**Expected output :**

```
 Array((CHN,2) ,(BNG,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are having has nothing to do with spark, it's a pure scala compilation error.

You can try in a scala (no spark at all) console :

```
scala> val iterableTest: Iterable[String] = Iterable("test")
iterableTest: Iterable[String] = List(test)

scala> iterableTest.count
<console>:29: error: missing argument list for method count in trait TraversableOnce
```

This is because [`Iterable` does not define a `count` (with no arguments) method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Iterable). It does define a count method, though, but which needs a predicate function argument, which is why you get this specific error about partially unapplied functions.

It does have a `size` method though, that you could swap in your sample to make it work.

Comment: I applied size method as per your answer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Elem you are getting is of type Iteratable[String] then try length method or size method  because Iteratable does not have count method if it does not work 
you can cast `Iteratable [String]` to List and try length method

Count method avalaible for RDD

Answer (score 1):

`count` - counts the occurrence of values provided in parameter condition (Boolean)

***count with your code:*** here  it counts # of occurrences of "2", "3"

```
scala> groupbykeyRDD.collect().foreach(println)
(CHN,CompactBuffer(2, 3))
(BNG,CompactBuffer(2, 65))

scala> groupbykeyRDD.map(elem => (elem._1 ,elem._2.count(_ == "2"))).collect
res14: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((CHN,1), (BNG,1))

scala> groupbykeyRDD.map(elem => (elem._1 ,elem._2.count(_ == "3"))).collect
res15: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((CHN,1), (BNG,0))
```

---

[***count with with small fix to your code:***](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-count-number-occurrences-character-in-string) if you twist you code this way than count should give you expected results:

`val keyvalueRDD = mapRDD.map(elem => (elem(0),1))`

***Test:***

```
scala> val groupbykeyRDD = mapRDD.map(elem => (elem(0),1)).groupByKey()
groupbykeyRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = ShuffledRDD[9] at groupByKey at <console>:18

scala> groupbykeyRDD.collect().foreach(println)
(CHN,CompactBuffer(1, 1))
(BNG,CompactBuffer(1, 1))

scala> groupbykeyRDD.map(elem => (elem._1 ,elem._2.count(_ == 1))).collect
res18: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((CHN,2), (BNG,2))
```

Comment: Nice explanation!!  From you answer I understood that  we can use Count by passing a function to it  that returns Boolean. Thanks Much.